# Merging multiple .txt files into a csv

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas, dataframe

*New to Python.

I'm trying to merge multiple text files into 1 csv; example below -

filename.csv

```
Alpha

0
0.1
0.15
0.2
0.25
0.3
```

text1.txt

```
Alpha,Beta
0,10
0.2,20
0.3,30
```

text2.txt

```
Alpha,Charlie
0.1,5
0.15,15
```

text3.txt

```
Alpha,Delta
0.1,10
0.15,20
0.2,50
0.3,10
```

Desired output in the csv file: -

filename.csv

```
Alpha  Beta  Charlie  Delta
  0     10     0        0
  0.1    0     5        10
  0.15   0     15       20
  0.2   20     0        50
  0.25   0     0        0
  0.3   30     0        10
```

The code I've been working with and others that were provided give me an answer similar to what is at the bottom of the page

```
def mergeData(indir="Dir Path", outdir="Dir Path"):
    dfs = []
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.txt")
    for filename in fileList:
        left= "/Path/Final.csv"
        right = filename
        output = "/Path/finalMerged.csv"
        leftDf = pandas.read_csv(left)
        rightDf = pandas.read_csv(right)
        mergedDf = pandas.merge(leftDf,rightDf,how='inner',on="Alpha", sort=True)
        dfs.append(mergedDf)
    outputDf = pandas.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
    outputDf = pandas.merge(leftDf, outputDf, how='inner', on='Alpha', sort=True, copy=False).fillna(0)
    print (outputDf)

    outputDf.to_csv(output, index=0)

mergeData()
```

The answer I get however is instead of the desired result: -

```
Alpha  Beta  Charlie  Delta
  0     10     0        0
  0.1    0     5        0
  0.1    0     0        10
  0.15   0     15       0
  0.15   0     0        20
  0.2   20     0        0
  0.2    0     0        50
  0.25   0     0        0
  0.3   30     0        0
  0.3    0     0        10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can create list of all `DataFrames` - `dfs`, in loop append `mergedDf` and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) all `DataFrames` to one:

```
import pandas
import glob
import os

def mergeData(indir="dir/path", outdir="dir/path"):
    dfs = []
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.txt")
    for filename in fileList:
        left= "/path/filename.csv"
        right = filename
        output = "/path/filename.csv"
        leftDf = pandas.read_csv(left)
        rightDf = pandas.read_csv(right)
        mergedDf = pandas.merge(leftDf,rightDf,how='right',on="Alpha", sort=True)
        dfs.append(mergedDf)
    outputDf = pandas.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
    #add missing rows from leftDf (in sample Alpha - 0.25) 
    #fill NaN values by 0
    outputDf = pandas.merge(leftDf,outputDf,how='left',on="Alpha", sort=True).fillna(0)
    #columns are converted to int
    outputDf[['Beta', 'Charlie']] = outputDf[['Beta', 'Charlie']].astype(int) 
    print (outputDf)

    outputDf.to_csv(output, index=0)

mergeData()

   Alpha  Beta  Charlie
0   0.00    10        0
1   0.10     0        5
2   0.15     0       15
3   0.20    20        0
4   0.25     0        0
5   0.30    30        0
```

EDIT:

Problem is you change parameter `how='left'` in second `merge` to `how='inner'`:

```
def mergeData(indir="Dir Path", outdir="Dir Path"):
    dfs = []
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.txt")
    for filename in fileList:
        left= "/Path/Final.csv"
        right = filename
        output = "/Path/finalMerged.csv"
        leftDf = pandas.read_csv(left)
        rightDf = pandas.read_csv(right)
        mergedDf = pandas.merge(leftDf,rightDf,how='inner',on="Alpha", sort=True)
        dfs.append(mergedDf)
    outputDf = pandas.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
    #need left join, not inner
    outputDf = pandas.merge(leftDf, outputDf, how='left', on='Alpha', sort=True, copy=False)
                     .fillna(0)
    print (outputDf)

    outputDf.to_csv(output, index=0)

mergeData()
```

```
   Alpha  Beta  Charlie  Delta
0   0.00  10.0      0.0    0.0
1   0.10   0.0      5.0    0.0
2   0.10   0.0      0.0   10.0
3   0.15   0.0     15.0    0.0
4   0.15   0.0      0.0   20.0
5   0.20  20.0      0.0    0.0
6   0.20   0.0      0.0   50.0
7   0.25   0.0      0.0    0.0
8   0.30  30.0      0.0    0.0
9   0.30   0.0      0.0   10.0
```

Comment: That did work. The issue is that its appending the way below.

Comment: I dont understand. What is problem?

Comment: That did work. It is how ever concatenating the data as below

          Alpha Beta Charlie
           0        10       0
           0.1      0        0
           0.15    0        0
           0.2     20       0
            0        0        0
           0.1      0        5
           0.15    0       15
           0.2      0        0

Comment: I little changed solution - do you use last version? I add comments to code what what changed.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: Yea I just had to comment out 
outputDf[['Beta', 'Charlie']] = outputDf[['Beta', 'Charlie']].astype(int)

Working with close to 2000 files.

Comment: Yes, it can be removed without problem. Thank you for accepting!

Comment: Jezrael, as soon as I start to merge multiple files, its appending and adding rows of the same alpha value still for each file. For example, if two files have values against 0.1, it'll add it the 0.1 row values twice, as well as for each other file (values of 0). I'm trying using the join method instead, which is a little better, only doing the former, but still have multiple rows for each alpha point.

Comment: Ok, what happen if duplicates between files? Can you add some sample and desired output? Or better create new question?

Comment: Updated the question to show the result and desired output.

Comment: Even with inner, its the same issue. I was playing around to see if the result changes whether I had inner or left/right/outer. its the same for that merge. If you see the result you posted its still adding a new row for the same alpha value for different files.

Comment: Interesting, for me it works nice. Second `merge` with `left` only add all rows, which are not in all looping files (in sample `0.25`). So there is problem? Or something different?  What is your pandas version? I test it in `pandas 0.18.1`.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is, I've been combing over it for a couple of days now. The only difference is the number of files I'm using (5, instead of 3 I've listed here and more rows). using 0.18.1 as well.

Comment: So it works with sample `3` files, but not with real `txt`?

Comment: It is weird. Pandas versions is same? If data are not confidental, you can send it by email in my profile.

Comment: it works if you the files dont have the same "alpha" value. If they do, then the same alpha value gets appended in the next row for each file. All this when reading in text files

Comment: Yes, I can send it over.

Comment: And please send me some sample of desired output for checking if it works right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.read_csv('samp1.csv',sep=',')
data2 = pd.read_csv('samp2.csv',sep=',')
data3 = pd.read_csv('samp3.csv',sep=',')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Alpha':data1.Alpha})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Alpha':data2.Alpha,'Beta':data2.Beta})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Alpha':data3.Alpha,'Charlie':data3.Charlie})
mergedDf = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on ='Alpha',sort=False)
mergedDf1 = pd.merge(mergedDf, df3, how='outer', on ='Alpha',sort=False)
a = pd.DataFrame(mergedDf1)
print(a.drop_duplicates())

output:
  Alpha  Beta  Charlie
0   0.00  10.0      NaN
1   0.10   NaN      5.0
2   0.15   NaN     15.0
3   0.20  20.0      NaN
4   0.25   NaN      NaN
5   0.30  30.0      NaN
```